# Linq to SQL using Lambda expressions together with Join, GroupBy, Count and Sum

Tags: sql, linq, join, lambda, count

I use this SQL statement to get what I want:

```
select count(o.Id) as order_amount, sum(r.Price) as Total_ordersum from Orders o join OrderRows r on o.Id = r.OrderId;
```

I tried this using Linq lambda expression to get the same result:

```
Orders
        .Join(OrderRows, o => o.Id, r => r.OrderId, (o,r) => new {o,r})
        .GroupBy(g => new {g.o.Id, g.r.Price})
        .Select(group => new {
            order_amount = group.Count(), 
            Total_ordersum  = group.Key.Price,
        });´
```

but I get three lines instead of just one with the total order amount and the sum of all orders. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

The LINQ and SQL queries are not equivalent. Your SQL query does not have `GROUP BY` while the LINQ query does group by order `Id` and record `Price`, which of course generates different results. Also the SQL query does sum the record `Price` while LINQ query does not.

You can achieve the same result in LINQ by using a sort of unusual `group by` *constant* operator:

```
var query = Orders
    .Join(OrderRows, o => o.Id, r => r.OrderId, (o, r) => new { o, r })
    .GroupBy(g => 0) // any constant would work
    .Select(g => new
    {
        order_amount = g.Count(), 
        Total_ordersum  = g.Sum(e => e.r.Price),
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan! But what does it mean where it says GroupBy(g => 0)? Aren't you supposed to use the declared variable in the lambda expression?

Comment: @HabilKantur Actually no. Some people use `_` to indicate unused lambda parameter like `GroupBy(_ => 0)`.